# Concatenation in PHP: missing white space

Tags: php, mysql, string-concatenation

I am doing a simple concatenation like this `$string = $a.' '.$b.' '.$c`
And `$b` is a variable that maybe null. So if `$b` is null, would the `$string = $a.' '.' '.$c`, and it seems like it in MySQL. 
However when I echo it, $string only has one space between $a and $c when `$b` is null, one white space went missing mysteriously. 
Anyone has any idea bout what's going on here?

Additional note: I am doing this because I forgot to check whether $middlename is null before the 60-hour parsing. So now in my database, there are names in correct form like `adam c. johnson` and names with incorrect form like `adam  johnson` that has two spaces between first and last name. If there is a way that I can eliminate the one additional space in those incorrect names, it could also solve my problem.

Code from comment:

```
$name = $list["firstname"].' '.$list["middlename"].' '.$list["lastname"];
if (strlen($name)>20) {
   //echo $name."<br>";
   $name_cut=substr($name,0,20);
   $stmt= $conn->stmt_init();
   $sql = 'UPDATE ? SET name=replace(name, \'?\', \'?\');';
   if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
      $stmt->bind_param('sss', $table, $name_cut, $name);
      $stmt->execute();
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you echoing to a web browser? Web browsers won't show more than one consecutive space.

Comment: Could we see some of your PHP code?

Comment: $name = $list["firstname"].' '.$list["middlename"].' '.$list["lastname"];
 if (strlen($name)>20) {
  //echo $name."<br>";
  $name_cut=substr($name,0,20);
  $stmt= $conn->stmt_init();
  $sql = 'UPDATE ? SET `name`=replace(`name`, \'?\', \'?\');';
  if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
   $stmt->bind_param('sss', $table, $name_cut, $name); 
   $stmt->execute();
  }

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to format it in the comment. Basically what I am trying to do is to replace the names that were being cut with the correct full names in database. I set the wrong length for field 'name' before.

Comment: As you've got a simple "two spaces" to "one space" replacement, the [`REPLACE` function seems fitting](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).

Answer (score 3):

Whitespace handling is defined in http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#h-9.1 (the HTML4 spec -- it does not seem to be in the HTML5 spec although I suppose it follows the same rules).

> In particular, user agents should collapse input white space sequences when producing output inter-word space. This can and should be done even in the absence of language information

If you want to print the actual space, put the contents of what you are printing inside of `<pre>`, an element with `white-space: pre` style, or use a non-breaking space entity (`&nbsp;`) instead of a space.

Answer (score 1):

Check if $list["middlename"] is NULL

```
if ($list["middlename"]==NULL){ 
  $ name = $list["firstname"].' '.$list["lastname"];
}
else{
     $ name = $list["firstname"].' '.$list["middlename"].' '.$list["lastname"];
}
if (strlen($name)>20) {
   //echo $name."<br>";
   $name_cut=substr($name,0,20);
   $stmt= $conn->stmt_init();
   $sql = 'UPDATE ? SET name=replace(name, \'?\', \'?\');';
   if ($stmt->prepare($sql)) {
      $stmt->bind_param('sss', $table, $name_cut, $name);
      $stmt->execute();
   }
}
```